# How to update column 1 with column 2 if condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to achieve something in a SQL Server 2008 database.

I problem is: all I need to do is happening in one table, I must update column with values that I have in same column but in other conditions..

I must do something like override prices where my `columnx` and `columny` have some specific values, with prices where `columnx` and `columny` have some other values, let me describe this in a image, and everything will be much more better explained:

[image]

As you can see on image guys, I need to update prices for doc_code 0 and doc_number 1 with values of price in case doc_code is 0 and doc_number is 2..

I tried with this, but that didn't work:

```
UPDATE Products
SET Products.price = temp.price,
    Products.pricetwo = temp.pricetwo
FROM
    Products,
    (SELECT price, pricetwo
     FROM Products
     WHERE Products.doc_code = 0 AND Products.doc_number = 2) temp
WHERE 
    Products.doc_code = 0 AND Products.doc_number = 1
```

I thought code above will do that like, okay, give me prices where doc code is 0 and doc number is 2 and set them on doc code 0 and doc number 1, but unfortunately that didn't help me..

I need to update ALL prices with doc_code=0 and doc_number=1, that means replace prices where doc_code=0 and doc_number=1 with prices where doc_code=0 and doc_number=2

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: At least I can't figure out how you decide from which row you want the prices to be updated, because there's a lot of duplicate rows, with same doc_id and doc_number. You should really somehow describe that.

Comment: @JamesZ that's how it is right now in the database, and it is confusing me, but there must be some kind of solution.. maybe move rows to another temp table and try smth with that or whatever :/

Comment: @JamesZ Maybe I could create temp tables and somehow organize it and after that insert it back to original table?

Comment: The problem I have is that you haven't shown any example how the prices should be updated from your table. If you don't explain that in your question, there's really no way others can guess that.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, then:

```
update p1
set p1.price = p2.price
  , p1.pricetwo = p2.pricetwo
from Products p1
  inner join Products p2
    on p1.doc_code = p2.doc_code
   and p1.doc_number = 1 /* this could also be in the where instead */
   and p2.doc_number = 2 /* this could also be in the where instead */
where p1.doc_code = 0;
```

but this will not work predictably if you have more than 1 row where `p2.doc_number = 2`

Comment: there is a lot of duplicate values so that means all values with doc code 0 and doc number 1 will get only one value from p2.doc_number=2 and all of the doc_number=1 will have same price? :/

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Right, that's what I was saying with the last line of my answer. If this is not what you are trying to do, then please update your question with your desired results.

Comment: I am really confused here also, I need to update ALL prices with doc_code=0 and doc_number=1 that mean replace them with prices where doc_code=0 and doc_number=2

Comment: @Roxy'Pro please update your question with a table showing your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image:

1. filter: there are 2 rows that have doc_code=0 and doc_number=1 (the two to be updated)
2. there is only 1 row with doc_code=0 and doc_number=2. It's price=1, should update any row from the above filter.

If I am wrong on deciphering, the below will not help. And, I did not write out the update statement, I wanted you to see how it worked.

```
    CREATE TABLE #products(
        [ID] [int] NULL,
        [doc_code] [int] NULL,
        [doc_number] [int] NULL,
        [price] [money] NULL,
        [price_two] [money] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY];
    GO
    INSERT INTO #products
               ([ID]
               ,[doc_code]
               ,[doc_number]
               ,[price]
               ,[price_two])
         VALUES
               (1,0,2,1,1)
               ,(2,0,1,5.6,4.6)
               ,(3,0,1,7,3)
               ,(4,1,1,2,2)
               ,(5,1,2,2,2)
               ,(6,1,2,3,3)
               ,(7,2,3,4,2)
               ,(8,2,0,10,5)
               ,(9,0,0,3,3)
               ,(10,1,0,5,2);
    GO
    --Select * FROM #products
    SELECT [ID]
        ,[doc_code]
        ,[doc_number]
        ,[price]
        ,[price_two]
        ,CAST([doc_code] as varchar)+''+CAST([doc_number] as varchar) conc
        ,(Select top 1 price_two FROM #products WHERE [doc_code]+''+[doc_number]= '02') new_price
    FROM #products
    WHERE CAST([doc_code] as varchar)+''+CAST([doc_number] as varchar)= '01'

    DROP Table #products
```